# How can I split from /dev/nvme0n1p3 to /dev/nvme0n1p2

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, mount

[image: GParted]

I only have one disk, an SSD on my laptop.
My disk status is as shown above. The /dev/nvme0n1p2 disk part (mounted at /) is too small. I plan to move 42GB from /dev/nvme0n1p3 to /dev/nvme0n1p2, but /dev/nvme0n1p3 is mounted at /home. So I can't unmount it and resize it. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

> but /dev/nvme0n1p3 is mounted at /home. So I can't unmount it and resize it

Boot into another system where nvme0n1p3 does not have to be mounted – for example, an Ubuntu live CD/USB or a "GPartedLive" system.

Side note: Your plan was resizing a partition from its 'beginning', and that actually involves *moving* the whole partition rightward, which will take quite a while for a ~450 GB partition. Since you have only ~12 GB used, it would probably be much faster to 1) back up the files somewhere else, 2) delete the /home partition, 3) resize "/" as needed, 4) create a new /home partition and restore files. (Or just use a single large "/" partition!)